# Profiling a partially evaluated program

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

For the purposes of profiling a partially evaluated program, I'm interested in knowing the best way to terminate a GHC program. This is useful for profiling programs that take a long time to run, possibly as long as forever.

With GHC 7.4.2, I was able to [profile a non-terminating program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23046895/925978) by enabling profiling (-prof -auto-all) and running my program with `+RTS -p`. This generated **incremental** profiling data. The program could be killed with `^c`, and the .prof file would contain data. In GHC 7.6 and later, it appears that *if* the program can be terminated with a single ^c, then profiling information is written to output. However (especially with newer versions of GHC?) a single ^c doesn't kill the program, at least not before I get impatient and hit ^c again. Usually two ^c will kill the program, but then no profiling data is written to output.

Concretely, consider the problem of trying to profile StupidFib.hs:

```
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
main = print $ fib 100
```

Compiling with -prof and running with +RTS -p, I can kill this program with a *single* ^c in the first approximately 10 seconds of execution, but after that only two ^c will do the job. Looking at my resources, this change appears to coincide with the program using all of my physical memory and moving to swap space, however that could be coincidental.

Why does ^c work sometimes, but not other times for the same program? What is the easiest way to ensure that profiling data will get printed when the program does not terminate on its own?

Comment: Are you sending ^C once or twice?

Comment: Usually I have to send it twice...once doesn't seem to kill the program.

Comment: Regardless of the GHC version, I've always found that if I can close it with one ^C it writes the profiling data and if it takes two, it doesn't. I'm not sure if there's a way around that though.

Comment: I don't think it matters how you kill the program, you can actually see the data when it is still running. I don't have 7.4.2 in front of me at the moment, but iirc that is how it works.

Comment: Well, here's an example I wrote up that seems to behave in this way (I've seen this in my own programs as well). It just eats memory quickly, so it's reasonable to kill it with one ^C, but it takes long enough that you could also use two ^Cs. If I enable profiling, it generates the profiling data with one ^C press, but it generates a blank file with two ^C presses: http://lpaste.net/114466. I'm using GHC 7.8.3. I'm guessing that when the RTS profiler receives a SIGINT, it writes its buffer to the file and cleans everything up. I'm not sure what happens with the second press exactly.

Comment: Interesting, so now I just have to find the appropriate place to ask about why it takes two `^c`s to kill some programs and one to kill others...

Comment: Although "technique" is probably too strong a word, something that has worked for me is to limit the stack size. In GHC 7.4, the stack size seems to be small and fixed, while in GHC 7.6 the infinite loop doesn't blow the stack on its own. However if you add option `+RTS -K1000..00` for some appropriate number of 0s, the stack will blow, and the profiling report will be generated.

Comment: For posterity, I have a stack project that i would build using `--profile` but the .prof file created when the executable was killed (even with just one signal) was empty. My usecase was to just timeout the program so i used `System.Timeout` to stop `main` which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the second signal is being delivered before the program has finished handling the first one, and at this point the signal's action has been reset to the default action, which (for SIGINT) is to terminate the program. Because of the swapping, there's a significant interval before the profiling code can write out the profiling data, during which time the program is vulnerable to a second SIGINT.

Moral of the story: be patient. If you wait long enough, the program will finish and the data will be written out. Regarding that second ^C, tell yourself, "Just don't do it!" :-)

One could argue that the Haskell runtime should set signal options such that a second SIGINT is ignored, but that would be risky because there'd be no easy way to terminate the program if things got really messed up trying to handle the signal.

You probably also want to avoid programs that exceed physical memory and induce a lot of swapping. At that point, your computation is effectively stalled and there's not much point in continuing. Use `+RTS -M` to limit the heap size to avoid getting into this situation.

Comment: Well, sometimes it just.. does not work. It seems like any deadlock would make it fail to stop gracefully.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Oh, nevermind my comment. Figured it out,  it was caused on the FFI boundary.