# Haskell program crashes when compiled but not when run through GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci, gloss

Program is here, although it's a lot of code and I don't know where the issue is:

https://github.com/rocurley/BlockPhys

My program hangs (gloss window displays whatever's behind it, and debugging information is not printed) whenever I run it. Ordinarily I would run it in profiling mode to find what looks like an infinite loop:

```
cabal run --ghc-options="-osuf p_o -prof -auto -auto-all"
```

But (despite what [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23046895/1454156) would lead me to believe) the profiling file is blank after I `^c` the program.

The other option for debugging infinite loops I know of is GHCI, but when I run `main` via `cabal repl`, the program works!

Does anyone have an idea where to start debugging this?

Comment: If all else fails, attach gdb and trace the machine instructions