# GHCi hangs when Ctrl+Cing from infinite loop with -fbreak-on-exception set

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

As the title says, I create an infinite loop in GHCi:

```
f x = x - 2
g x = if f x < x then g (f x + 2) else x
g 2
```

Normally pressing Ctrl+C yields "Interrupted." and a return to the GHCi prompt.  If I `:set -fbreak-on-exception` beforehand though, Ctrl+C does not break the loop and my only recourse is to kill the program externally.

Is there a way to break into infinite loops using GHCi?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Cool! Smells buggy to me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behaviour on GHC version 8.0.